# Stuck in Space - Part I

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

I've been transported through a wormhole to a new planet in a new universe.

Standard stuff, really.

But something is... *off* about this planet. Sometimes, walking around it, I just feel like I'm going in the wrong direction entirely.  And it gets weirder. When I first arrived, I decided to make the best of the situation and stick a flag in the ground, claiming the land as my own. That flag became my home base, but one day during my exploring I got particularly lost and found the *bottom of the flagpole* sticking out of the ground. I don't remember how I got back that night, but I eventually stumbled back to the original flag - absolutely untouched.

Thanks to some recent developments, I've been able to contact a team of mathematicians on the other side of the wormhole to help resolve my problems. It seems the communication is one-way, though, because they are now stuck in the wormhole trying to get to my side. The only thing that got through seems like a piece of one of their notes:

```
  <
v   v  Z,Z(F2),0,...
  >
```

What is this planet, and what is this universe? Where the hell am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are on

> [a Klein bottle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle)

The note shows

> on the left, a diagram showing how to make one by identifying edges of a rectangle, and on the right the homology groups of the Klein bottle (though the notation is a little peculiar).

And

> the Klein bottle is nonorientable, which is how you were able to find yourself on the "wrong side" of it after some wandering around.

As for the universe,

> it's hard to say much with confidence, but your ambient space can't be R^3 because you can't embed a Klein bottle in that. Perhaps somewhere with more dimensions, or perhaps the universe itself is nonorientable.

Comment: You got it! As to the universe, I'd agree there isn't enough information to make a definite conclusion, I just tried to imply we were in R^4 with the "I just feel like I'm going in the wrong direction entirely". Stick around for part II - it gets a lot harder.